# Get Specific Attribute on Route Method from WebAPI Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a Controller which implements an AuthorizableApi Class.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthorizableRoute : Attribute { }

public class AuthorizableApi : ApiController
{
    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        /* Add functionality here to secure the API */
        return base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This allows me to secure an entire controller, however I also want to be able secure a single action.
Using the controllerContext I can get the controller and route but I don't know if it's possible to get an attribute on that action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AuthorizableRoute]
    public HttpResponseMessage DataAction([FromBody] DataType data)
    {
        /* Actions */
    }
```

So, I'd like to be able to do something like...

`if(Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(myRoute, typeof (AuthorizableRoute)) != null) { }`

If this isn't possible then what could be a viable alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by implementing a Filter. You should however inherit the AuthorizationFilterAttribute and implement the OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext context) method.
It should be something like this:

```
public class AuthorizableRouteFilterAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext context)
   {  
      IPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;            
      /*Your authorization check here*/

      if (!principal.IsInRole("YourRole")) // or whatever check you make
      {
           context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
           return;
      }
   }        
}


[HttpPost]
[AuthorizableRouteFilter]
public HttpResponseMessage DataAction([FromBody] DataType data)
{
    /* Actions */
}
```

Comment: I discovered and ended up using AuthorizeAttribute, but after some quick research it looks like AuthorizationFilterAttribute is the better way to go. Thanks!